# VLOOKUP N/A Error

Tags: excel, vlookup

I had a quick question about VLOOKUP in Excel.  Suppose I create a table of three rows and two columns with no headers.  Say that I supply the first column with the categories 'bad' 'okay and 'good' and the second with the numbers 0,1,2.  If I have a single column somewhere else in the worksheet containing 0s 1s and 2s I understand that my VLOOKUP should look as follows:

VLOOKUP(an entry in the column of 0s 1s and 2s, the table of three rows and two columns, 2, FALSE).

However, I get an N/A value.  Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: VLOOKUP() needs to have the column with the 0s, 1s, and 2s to the left of the other columns.....so it should be the first column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VLOOKUP` takes the entry (first part of function) and looks in column 1 of the table, that is, in your example, it is looking in the column containing 'Good', 'Okay' and 'Bad' and since it doesn't find anything (0, 1 or 2), it returns `#N/A`.

Turn around your table so that 0, 1 and 2 are first and then in the next column have 'Good', 'Okay' and 'Bad' and retype your formula in.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  Why then does VLOOKUP ask to specify a column though if it always takes the first?

Comment: @Stopwatch The column specified is the column from which the value is to be returned. If you had 3 columns, and use 3, VLOOKUP will return the values from the 3rd column.

Answer (score 2):

For `VLOOKUP` to work you'd need the table to have the number column to the left of the text column (lookup range is always 1st column of the "table array"), so you either need to switch those and use VLOOKUP or leave the current setup and use `INDEX/MATCH`

`=INDEX(1st column of table,MATCH(an entry in the column of 0s 1s and 2s, 2nd column of table,0))`

Comment: +1 Was going to put the alternative but had to go away from the keyboard for some time =P